# rails puma постоянный рост используемой памяти

Tags: ruby-on-rails, веб-сервер

Имеется небольшое приложение на rails(4.2.6), в качестве веб-сервера используется nginx+puma(3.4.0). Сервер Debian 8.1 64bit. 
Заметил одну странную вещь, с каждым запросом, используемое процессами puma количество памяти растет, и никогда не снижается(во время отсутствия каких либо запросов). Это приводит к тому, что  ОЗУ на сервере (512 мб) заканчивается, и останавливается служба postgres(9.4). Пробовал разное количество воркеров, нитей, работа в кластерном режиме и в обычном - результат всегда один и тот же. После нескольких тяжелых запросов ОЗУ заканчивается.
Неужели так и должно быть? Какие есть пути устранения такой проблемы? По информации, которую я нашел, Puma - это один из лучших выборов для избежания проблемы медленных клиентов и долгих запросов.
Текущий конфиг такой:

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

...

threads 2,4

...
workers 1

preload_app!

on_restart do
  puts 'Refreshing Gemfile'
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "/home/.../current/Gemfile"
end

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

Comment: 512Мб для RoR приложения (с учетом потребоности операционной системы) к сожалению мало. Нужен как минимум 1Гб.

Comment: @cheops, но ведь этой памяти мне с лихвой хватает если делать обычные запросы(основная масса запросов у меня мелкие, с откликом в пределах 500ms вместе с рендером). И только с жирным запросом(рендер ~12к записей в json с обработкой каждой записи), который рендерится около 10 сек, память начинает расти, и после завершения запроса не освобождается. Т.е сделали один запрос, памяти еще осталось, сервер жив. Сделали еще пару - память закончилась, сервер встал

Comment: т.е весь вопрос пока в том почему после завершения запроса используемая память не снижается обратно к предыдущему значению

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Описанное в ответе [реально не совсем правда](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d94ea30a576136d93b122b6eb69971b18be927d5/gc.c#L1459-L1462).*

*GC может освобождать память, но темпы освобождения могут быть меньше темпов роста. Вне синтетических тестов обычно так и есть.*

***Ответ подлежит переработке с учётом этого факта.***

---

Да, это из-за особенностей работы GC в самом Ruby. Он держит собственный пул памяти, увеличивая его при необходимости, но **никогда не уменьшая**. И тому есть причина.

Объекты, "подметённые" сборщиком мусора, освобождают память с точки зрения интерпретатора, но не с точки зрения ОС. Посему, только тот факт, что память занята процессом, не означает, что в ней действительно есть что-то ценное **для программы**, скорее всего, это просто "запас", в котором интерпретатор будет размещать новые объекты сам, не дёргая аллокатор ОС.

Соответственно, в каждый момент времени процесс будет занимать **максимум** того, что ему было нужно за всё время его жизни. Размер пула будет с небольшим запасом равен пиковому потреблению памяти.

---

Беда с большими объектами в том, что они требуют большие **последовательные** области памяти. И если такой блок в пуле не находится, то... пул **ещё** увеличивается на такую величину, чтобы большой объект влез!

Эту проблему можно было б частично победить, используя сборщик мусора с "уплотнением" (compaction), когда GC в процессе работы "перекладывает" мелкие объекты поближе друг к другу, тем самым образуя более крупные **последовательные** области свободной памяти. Это же могло бы позволить отдавать крупные "хвосты" незанятой памяти обратно в ОС. Но это здорово усложняет работу С-шных расширений, которые запоминают, где был объект, непосредственно по адресу в памяти. Нельзя просто сказать им "я вон тот объект подвинул, имей в виду".

---

Сделать можно много чего.

- Пол-гигабайта на целое рельсовое приложение и хранилища данных это... крайне немного. Есть смысл добавить, если не физической ОЗУ, то хотя бы подкачки.
- Подкрутить garbage collector на более осторожное расширение пула и частые срабатывания. Это вряд ли поможет, но может немножко отсрочить неизбежное. Это довольно обширная и опасная тема, требующая тщательного стресс-тестирования на каждое изменение.
- *(Самый богатый на приключения)* Реально снизить пиковое потребление памяти, отдавая большие ответы по кусочкам, чтобы GC успевал подчищать то, что уже отослано клиенту. Есть `ActionController::Live`, с помощью которого [можно писать ответ в поток по кусочкам](https://github.com/brianhempel/stream_json_demo/blob/master/app/controllers/random_numbers_controller.rb), не загружая все исходные данные для него в память.